# User specific firebase functions secrets

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need some help (more of an advice), basically I have an app in which user can purchase scratch-cards, when purchased, user will have an option to activate it, after activating, the encrypted scratch-card url gets decrypted (done by me), and now I replace the encrypted url with this newly activated decrypted url in my firestore collection, but to add more security I wanted to store it as a `firebase functions secret` (as I'm using firebase and its cloud functions), so I'm confused as to how do I manage it and store user specific decrypted url in firebase functions secrets, because as per the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env it looks like we can only store a single secret value like this: `firebase functions:secrets:set SECRET_NAME` but I want it to be user specific because for each user, there could be many scratch-cards and their decrypted url, I do not want them to store as it is inside my firestore collection, I want it to store in firebase functions secrets.

For example, I have user collection:

```
users/12345/
 -> decryptedURL:some_link_to_firebase_secret
```

So, this `some_link_to_firebase_secret` could be a url from which a user can get the decrypted URL from firebase functions secrets, and it should belong to only this specific user. Is it possible? Or any other approach?

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Secrets are for storing developer-secrets not user-secrets. For storing secret values from the user, use a database and its security mechanism. For example, if you store the value in one of Firebase's databases (Firestore or the Realtime Database) you'd use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to ensure the user can't read them.